# How to draw 3 vectors using Graphics3D?

Tags: graphics3d, homework

Given two vectors

```
A = {1, 0, -2}
B = {0, 1, 1}
```

C is the cross product of A and B, so

```
C = {2, -1, -1}
```

Plot vectors `A`, `B`, and `C` on the same plot.

Comment: How do you want the plot to look? Should the vectors appears as arrows or line segments projecting from the origin, or just points?

Comment: I figured it out, thank you though! But to answer your question anyway, the vectors projecting from the origin.

Comment: Good for you. It is always best when you can figure things out for yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Graphics3D[{Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, a}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, b}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, c}]}]
```

[image]